# Can't start bash script on ubuntu docker container

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker

it's been a few days now but I really can't understand how to run a bash script correctly in ubuntu/xenial64 using docker. Any clarifications will be very appreciated.

I created a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY setup.sh /setup.sh
RUN chmod +x /setup.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/setup.sh" ]
```

The error returned is: `standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`

But why?? If I run `ls` the file is correctly placed on the root. I also tried using `CMD ["/setup.sh"]`. My script file has a shebang like this `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this Dockerfile, it must be in your setup.sh

Comment: Can you run /bin/bash in this container?

Comment: @thatotherguy I tried to create a new Dockerfile using alpine and writing `CMD ["echo", "hello world"]` to test it but it says `Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"echo hello world\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
` so I guess I can't do anything... I'm running Windows 10 LTSB with cygwin. Docker version is 17.12.0-ce